# Assign weights to features for a distance-based classifier (e.g KNN)

Tags: python, nlp, distance, weighted

I have a lot of text (+4mio documents) which is made up of very short text (text from banktransaction).

My "sentence embedding" consists of `CountVetorizer` (it seems to work better than Tf-IDF).

This works fairly well, but I do know that some words in the text are just "noisy" and does nothing but harm say I e.g have these two texts `["payment facebook/12388", "payment facebook/12389"]` which are very similar but only differs by the number after `"/"`.

I have made some text-cleaning, removed known stopwords (and also based on frequency) etc. which takes care of most of such issues, but it still happens, and I can't sit looking through more than 4 mio texts. I was then wondering, if there's  some way of  creating a weighted-distance thus somehow learn which features/words are useable and which are not - just like the weights in e.g at Logistic Regression.

I am using the text for a classification problem with +90.000 classes, thus KNN (and variants of that) have shown to be the best classifier (Logistic Regression simply takes way too long to train and performs rather poorly compared to KNN). I very much assume that if I could add some weights to each feature that could reduce those noisy-words.

One way of doing it is (assuming the "sentence"-vectors are unit-vectors) to add/reduce some constant one at a time to each feature and see, if that increases or decreases the performance.
This, of course, might take quite a while and is rather sub-optimal thus I wonder, if there's some way of doing that "better"? I haven't been able to find it.

Note, I'm interested in how to find the "find the optimal weight" in case we have to write it ourself and can't use e.g sklearns classifier.